# How to run a scheduled containerized job and minimize GCP costs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scheduled-tasks, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to run every 20 minutes a containerized python job using GCP. The job itself takes ~10 minutes to complete.

Currently I am running it as a CronJob in a zonal GKE cluster with 1 worker node.

Is there any other best practice? I want to know the best practice that also minimizes costs.

My requirements are:

- Use containerized application
- Schedule the job every 20 minutes
- Use GPU
- Run a single job instance only
- Minimize costs

I have seen there are other technologies such as Cloud Scheduler, Cloud Pub/Sub, Cloud Functions but don't know if they can be used for my requirements.

Also, I have seen that preemptible VMs exist on GKE with 80% gain in cost. My job can be stopped and restarted. It just runs a single transaction where it reads some data from a DB, does some preprocessing and at the end writes the result back in DB.

The only concern is this: When a node is preempted by Google how long it takes to come back? Some minutes? An hour? Also, when the GKE cluster has no nodes it will automatically create one?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run your cluster in [GKE Autopilot mode](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview). With GKE Autopilot, you only have to pay for time time for which your app is consuming resources. It is the perfect use case for a CRON job.

- You don't need to make any changes in your code or deployment strategy. Just create a new GKE cluster and select the cluster type as autopilot.

Comment: AFAIK, GKE autopilot isn't compliant with GPU for now.

Comment: Hi all! Yes, it seems GKE autopilot is a new feature and haven't used it yet. For example, in such a case the cluster and the worker nodes (Compute Engine VMs) aren't billed as long as they are alive? I will only pay for the pods related to CronJob resource? If that's the case it is very nice! However, GPU is very important for me. Actually I am using some deep learning models for inference only.

Answer (score 1):

The preempted instances goes back very quickly (1 minutes or less) in ideal condition, I mean, there is enough resources in the zone to create your instance, but it can take hours or days if the zone is over used. Google priorises the regular instance at the expense of the preemptible.

In summary, you haven't any guarantee, but you pay only 20% of regular price! Always a matter of tradeoff.

---

If you have a container, you can shift gear and have a look to [AI Platform custom container training](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/custom-containers-training). Forgive the meaning of the name, keep in mind that you can provision resources on demand to run your container and they are destroyed when the workload ends. You have a small overhead (about 2 minutes to start the container and 1 minutes at the end to destroy the environment) but I'm sure that can fit your use case

Comment: Hi! AI Platform is only for training models? My container uses some already pre-trained deep learning models only for inference. I don't want to train new models. The easiest for me is to try out the preemptible VMs in GKE and see how things will go. The 1-minute delay is very nice for my use case as best case scenario. Is there a way to know if a zone is over used? Currently my zonal cluster is deployed in us-central1-a and if I could know somehow that some other zone is usually not overloaded I could use this instead.

Comment: My scheduled container actually reads some data from Cloud SQL db, does some ML inference and then writes back to the db some predictions.

Comment: That's the hack: AI Platform custom container training is designed to run containers for long training job (hours or days!). But in reality, the platform absolutely don't know what run in your container. Therefore, you can simply run whatever you want in the container and deploy it on the AI Platform training. I repeat: forgive the name, leverage the concept!

Comment: The prediction of a zone overuse is hard. In addition, it depends on the type of CPU and GPU that you use. And what will use the other Google Cloud customer. The resources availability can never occur, or occur frequently.